# ASP.NET C# - Edit Account Page INSERT and UPDATE data

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm not a strong coder and quite new to C#. I am having problems with the edit account page of the website that I am trying to create. I am trying to update and insert data into the database and they don't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
public partial class EditAccount : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    private readonly object MessageBox;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlCommand com;
            string str;

            conn.Open();
            str = "SELECT Address.HouseNumber, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, Address.City, Address.PostCode, CardDetails.CardDetailsID, CardDetails.NameOnCard, CardDetails.NameOfCard, CardDetails.CardNumber, CardDetails.CardExpiryDate, CardDetails.CVV, AddressType.AddressTypeDescription, Member.MemberID, Member.MemberName, Member.Phone, Member.Email, Member.Username FROM Address FULL JOIN AddressType ON Address.AddressTypeID = AddressType.AddressTypeID FULL JOIN Member ON AddressType.MemberID = Member.MemberID FULL JOIN CardDetails ON Member.MemberID = CardDetails.MemberID WHERE Member.Email = '" + Session["Email"] + "'";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                TxtEName.Text = reader["MemberName"].ToString();
                LblEUser.Text = reader["Username"].ToString();
                TxtEEmail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
                TxtEPhone.Text = reader["Phone"].ToString();
                TxtEType.Text = reader["AddressTypeDescription"].ToString();
                TxtEHouse.Text = reader["HouseNumber"].ToString();
                TxtEA1.Text = reader["AddressLine1"].ToString();
                TxtEA2.Text = reader["AddressLine2"].ToString();
                TxtECity.Text = reader["City"].ToString();
                TxtEPostcode.Text = reader["PostCode"].ToString();
                TxtENameOf.Text = reader["NameOfCard"].ToString();
                TxtENameOn.Text = reader["NameOnCard"].ToString();
                TxtECardNo.Text = reader["CardNumber"].ToString();
                TxtEExpDate.Text = reader["CardExpiryDate"].ToString();
                TxtECVV.Text = reader["CVV"].ToString();

                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter str = new SqlDataAdapter ("SELECT Address.HouseNumber, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, Address.City, Address.PostCode, CardDetails.NameOnCard, CardDetails.NameOfCard, CardDetails.CardNumber, CardDetails.CardExpiryDate, CardDetails.CVV, AddressType.AddressTypeDescription, Member.MemberName, Member.Phone, Member.Email, Member.Username FROM Address FULL JOIN AddressType ON Address.AddressTypeID = AddressType.AddressTypeID FULL JOIN Member ON AddressType.MemberID = Member.MemberID FULL JOIN CardDetails ON Member.MemberID = CardDetails.MemberID WHERE Member.Email = '" + Session["Email"] + "'",conn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        str.Fill(ds);



        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Member SET MemberName = '" + TxtEName.Text + "', Email = '" + TxtEEmail.Text + "', Phone = '" + TxtEPhone.Text + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand updateCommand1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Address SET HouseNumber ='" + TxtEHouse.Text + "', AddressLine1 = '" + TxtEA1.Text + "', AddressLine2 = '" + TxtEA2.Text + "', City = '" + TxtECity.Text + "',PostCode = '" + TxtEPostcode.Text + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand updateCommand2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE AddressType SET AddressTypeDescription = '" + TxtEType.Text + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand updateCommand3 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE CardDetails SET NameOnCard = '" + TxtENameOn.Text + "', NameOfCard = '" + TxtENameOf.Text + "', CardNumber = '" + TxtECardNo.Text + "', CardExpiryDate = '" + TxtEExpDate.Text + "', CVV = '" + TxtECVV.Text + "'", conn);

            updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            updateCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            updateCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            updateCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Changes saved')</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AddressType (AddressTypeDescription) VALUES (@AddressTypeDescription)", conn);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressTypeDescription", TxtEType.Text);
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand insertCommand1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Address (HouseNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, PostCode) VALUES (@HouseNumber, @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @City, @PostCode)", conn);

            insertCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HouseNumber", TxtEHouse.Text);
            insertCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine1", TxtEA1.Text);
            insertCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine2", TxtEA2.Text);
            insertCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TxtECity.Text);
            insertCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", TxtEPostcode.Text);
            insertCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand insertCommand2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CardDetails (NameOnCard, NameOfCard, CardNumber, CardExpiryDate, CVV) VALUES (@NameOnCard, @NameOfCard, @CardNumber, @CardExpiryDate, @CVV)", conn);
            insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameOnCard", TxtENameOn.Text);
            insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameOfCard", TxtENameOf.Text);
            insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardNumber", TxtECardNo.Text);
            insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardExpiryDate", TxtEExpDate.Text);
            insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CVV", TxtECVV.Text);
            insertCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Changes saved')</script>");
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `they don't seem to work.` that's not the clear explanation of problem. What happens when you run this code? Are you getting error? What error? Did you debug the code? What are the findings of debugging?

Comment: "they don't seem to work." Is not a great problem description. What errors are you getting? What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should? On a side you are also wide open to SQL Injection attacts. Use SQL Parameters instead of building the SQL Queries.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You also need to put a bit of thought into error handling here with all those DB statements. What happens if your 2nd insert fails? You now have incomplete data. The same with all those updates. You should look at Transactions both on the DB side and the .net side.

Comment: One thing that stands out.... your update statements will update **every** row! You should have some kind of identifier... e.g `UPDATE Member SET ..... WHERE MemberId=@MemberId`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Right, so this edit account page contains text boxes and the user will need to insert their data into these text boxes but my sql commands did not work because when i actually pressed the save button it did not update/insert the data. I have checked the database and no data was updated or inserted. Also, I am not getting any errors and yes i did debug the code. and it gave me this : The thread 0x457c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll